# Outlook AddIn: showing popup while dragging mail in Outlook

Tags: c#, wpf, outlook

I have an outlook addin which shows a popup after sending mail which asks the user whether he/she wants to save the mail. 
The problem is that this popup is shown when a mail is added to the sent folder.
So when you send a mail and immediately start dragging a mail to another folder because, e.g. you want to clean up mails, then the popup shows when you're in the middle of dragging which stops the dragging and makes the popup with the question unresponsive to the mouse.

Is there any way around this?

Thanks in advance!

The event for an mail being added to sent folder is set in the Ribbon Load method:

```
        private void CodexRibbon_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Globals.ThisAddIn.FirstLoadComplete)
        {
            Messenger.Default.Register<object>(this, ItemSend);
            Globals.ThisAddIn.FirstLoadComplete = true;
        }
    }
```

The question is asked as follows:

```
        private void ItemSend(object item)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show(@" Wilt u de zojuist verzonden e-mail opslaan?", @"Opslaan in Codex", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            ShowSaveWindow(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to find out if the control is inside the `DoDragDrop` Windows API function (you can patch it and have the patched version set some kind of a global flag before entering the original function, but I don't think that will be a good idea in .Net).

Try to display the message box in the `Application.ItemSend`event handler, mark the message somehow (user property?), then do the processing in `Items.ItemAdd` without a message box.